# Impersonnate admnistrator for a function only in .net

Tags: .net, impersonation, administrator

I have a program in which I need to make some changes in folders access right and normally, only the administrator user would be allowed to do that. However, for a particular case, I must be able to 'pretend' I am the administrator and make some changes even though the user who is running the application does not have administrator privileges.

Is there any way to perform such task ?

thanks

EDIT : Having the username/password is not a problem if this is required.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows users & permissions?

Comment: Yes, we have an AD and I need to pretend I am the administrator for a short while, but I need to revert back to the normal user once the task is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this for current user:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = 
    ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

//Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here.

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

If you are looking to impersonate specific user then some more work will be required:

http://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

Comment: This sounds pretty complicated to impersonate a single user. I think I'll put this in a dll so that I can reuse it plenty.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ImpersonationDemo
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    // Test harness. 
    // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand FullTrust.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
        try
        {
            string userName, domainName;
            // Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password using the 
            // unmanaged LogonUser method. 
            // The local machine name can be used for the domain name to impersonate a user on this machine.
            Console.Write("Enter the name of the domain on which to log on: ");
            domainName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter the login of a user on {0} that you wish to impersonate: ", domainName);
            userName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter the password for {0}: ", userName);

            const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            //This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token. 
            const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token. 
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(userName, domainName, Console.ReadLine(),
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                out safeTokenHandle);

            Console.WriteLine("LogonUser called.");

            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine("LogonUser failed with error code : {0}", ret);
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }
            using (safeTokenHandle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did LogonUser Succeed? " + (returnValue ? "Yes" : "No"));
                Console.WriteLine("Value of Windows NT token: " + safeTokenHandle);

                // Check the identity.
                Console.WriteLine("Before impersonation: "
                    + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
                WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
                using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                {

                    // Check the identity.
                    Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: "
                        + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
                }
                // Releasing the context object stops the impersonation 
                // Check the identity.
                Console.WriteLine("After closing the context: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred. " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx